# How to fix (eb init) NotAuthorizedError

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
Select a default region
1.  us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2.  us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3.  us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4.  eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
5.  eu-central-1 : EU (Frankfurt)
6.  ap-south-1 : Asia Pacific (Mumbai)
7.  ap-southeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Singapore)
8.  ap-southeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Sydney)
9.  ap-northeast-1 : Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
10. ap-northeast-2 : Asia Pacific (Seoul)
11. sa-east-1 : South America (Sao Paulo)
12. cn-north-1 : China (Beijing)
13. cn-northwest-1 : China (Ningxia)
14. us-east-2   :   US  East (Ohio)
15. ca-central-1 :  Canada (Central)
16. eu-west-2   :   EU  (London)
17. eu-west-3   :   EU  (Paris)
(default is 3): 1

Enter Application Name (default is "project93"):
```

The error returned is:

> `ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. User: arn:aws:iam::781394009687:user/Yunseong is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplication on resource: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1:781394009687:application/project93`

When I try 'eb init' in terminal, that error is returned.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are facing is an IAM permissions error for the user Yunseong; user `Yunseong` is not authorized to perform `elasticBeanstalk:CreateApplication` on resource `project93`

To resolve this add an IAM policy to ALLOW `elasticBeanstalk:CreateApplication` to user:Yunseong. Best practice is to scope this to the individual resource you need, `project93` (you’ll need the full ARN).

It’s worth pointing out that EB applications can require many permissions and you’ll likely need to repeat the process of following the permissions errors until you have the correct permissions. There are a number of strategies you can use to expedite this process, but an alternative to this, which could be a very time consuming process, would be to simply have a user with higher permissions (admin) in the target account deploy the app.

Comment: THank you !! have a nice day ~ :)